# Is it possible to set a specific concurrency number for Gatling tests?

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I knew how I can run all the scenarios concurrenctly, like

```
setUp(
  scenario1.inject(injectionProfile1),
  scenario2.inject(injectionProfile2)
)
```

And I just wonder how can I implement such a test scenario:

I can set the concurrency number, e.g, 2, in the code or in some other config file, then the test could run by this concurrency number.

Comment: Do you want call the same scenario and inject profile just N times? Or it can be various, as in your example?

Comment: My bad, maybe I didn't describe my issue very clearly. 

For example, given there are 5 scenarios, 
when the concurrent number is 2, 
then what I expect is to run 2 scenarios at a time.

Comment: And of course the scenarios could be different.

Comment: And I tried to implement this function by myself with scala reflection, sadly it's failed with 'Simulations can't be instantiated directly but only by Gatling.'

Comment: At first create variable which stores all scenarios with inject profile, and then take disered number 
`val storage = List(
    scenario1.inject(injectionProfile1),
    scenario2.inject(injectionProfile2),
    scenario2.inject(injectionProfile3)
  )

  setUp(
    storage.take(2)
  )`

Comment: @Amerousful Thanks Amerousful! 
It does work for the first 2 scenarios, and what should I do if I want to continue to run the rest scenarios? Cuz I find the func. setUp can only be called once.

Comment: You can't change anything in runtime, only once before a run.